# Error loading dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, package, loading

I'm trying to load the dplyr package,  but receive the following message:

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
>   vI[[i]]) :    namespace ‘DBI’ 0.3.1 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.1 is
>   required

I tried `update.packages()` for dplyr and DBI but didn't change anything. I used this package other times, but only now I'm getting this problem. Any suggestion??